# Are there keyboard shortcuts for Home, End, PageDown, and PageUp in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard

How do I set keyboard shortcuts for <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> on a 13" MacBook Pro? Are there default keyboard shortcuts? Or can I do it with Automator (and if so, how)?

I want them to work the same way that <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> do on all Windows apps.

---

I also want general solution I get that [Kyle Cronin♦](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/home-end-pagedown-pageup-on-a-macbook-pro/3688#3688) was do the same in some apps, but what about others? is there any tricky solution?

Answer (score 95):

You can do page up/down and home/end on a Macbook keyboard by using the <kbd>fn</kbd> and the arrow keys:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> is <kbd>PageUp</kbd>
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is <kbd>PageDown</kbd>
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> is <kbd>Home</kbd>
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> is <kbd>End</kbd>

Comment: @kyle fn + ->  and fn + <- not work fine for me. in some apps it's work right but in some apps it works strange.

Comment: The keystrokes Kyle Cronin provided are correct.  Bear in mind that Home and End do not always behave the same way on OS X as they do on other OSes.

Comment: +agreed.  There's quite a bit of difference from the windows functionality.  Some apps act like windows with these keys, others don't.

Comment: @calavera How can I define keystroke for home and end to do exactly the same as windows?

Comment: @am1rr3za: you can't do it in the OS... it's the way the apps themselves are programmed that defines how they handle those keys.  What specific apps are you having trouble with?

Comment: @calavera I have problem With Eclipse and also Browser address bar

Comment: For the browser address bar (and pretty much any text situation), command-left and right replicate Windows' home and end.  As a bonus, option-left and right does the same as Windows' control-left and right.

Comment: This doesn't work on terminal, though

Comment: @Manu Works for me in terminal. The fn+arrow keys work exactly the same as the dedicated home/end/pgup/pgdn keys on my Apple Keyboard.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> works like a PC's <kbd>End</kbd> (moves the cursor to the end of the line). <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> works like a PC's <kbd>Home</kbd> (moves to the beginning of the line). <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Emacs-style keybindings) work in most OS X applications as well.

Answer (score 7):

I found another solution for you while I was playing around with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).  Check out the settings pictured below.  See anything you like? :)

[image: keyremap4macbook settings]

Comment: +1 for your answer but I don'thave time now to test it, later I test and tell it solve my problem or not.

Comment: None of those address PageUp/PageDown on a MacBook

Comment: It's now at https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Answer (score 6):

On my MBP it's:
<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> for HOME
and
<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> for END

Comment: These are the shortcuts I was hunting for. I wanted to jump to the beginning or end of a document.

Comment: You also have cmd+up and cmd+down, which do the same thing and require one less finger on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse it appears that these keys aren't even set to anything by default, at least in my installation.  You probably need to set them in the preferences:

[image: eclicpse page up and page down]

I don't know exactly where the end and home Windows-like functions are in this screen, I couldn't find anything yet that sounds like what they do.  Something like "move cursor to end\beginning of line" was what I was looking for.

If you're talking about Safari's address bar, try <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for end and home.  Those work in lots of other apps as well.

Comment: +1 for your answer but I want find general solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, you can use <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for home and <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> for end. Although this is on a Swedish keyboard.